# How to only show one row at a time in a collapsible table, toggle

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that toggles rows in my table. All my rows use the class "labels" for the click, and "hide" to toggle the hidden data. How do I make it so the user is only able to see one row of its hidden data at a time instead of clicking on multiple and seeing all of them?

```
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all remaining elements with the help of [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method and hide.

```
$('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
    // cache element reference
    let $ele = $(this).parents().next('.hide');
    // toggle element
    $ele.toggle();
    // hide remaining 
    $('.hide').not($ele).hide();
});
```